# Can anyone help me create a simple machine learning algorithm for a 'pet' application

Tags: java, algorithm, machine-learning, genetic-algorithm

I'm creating an organism simulator for Android, so I guess the algorithm would ideally be in Java. I realize that there is a whole Stanford course on Machine Learning available on youtube, but I simply don't have the time to sit through the whole thing, and I think for my purposes the solution could be very simple.

The organism will be interacted with by the touchscreen primarily, or even if it's interacted with through the mic or accelerometer the inputs in the algorithm will mostly amount to coordinate positions for the different limbs. I think it will be inelegant to have a 'scolding' or 'rewarding' mechanism for random behaviors, so I would like to avoid that. So tracking general directions or patterns in movements and being able to repeat them when they have a high enough frequency would be the goal.

To be honest I'm not really sure how hard this is to accomplish, but I'd like to hear any feedback to know how much more I have to research before I can implement it.

EDIT: Is this a genetic algorithm? The problem is I have no idea how to measure a successful or non successful evolution.

EDIT 2: Okay, I'll try to add as much detail as possible. The application is still in concept stage at the moment, but I just wanted to know how difficult the algorithm would be to put it. So I'm building it in Processing, which is really just Java. The organism would be comprised of limbs that have a fixed distance between them, but are allowed to move independently from the center piece. The limbs move around freely and would find random points periodically to ease to. The organism would have a center appendage that has x and y coordinates as well, and each of the outer limbs would move in relation to that. The user could interact with the organism by manually moving the appendages or the center piece with drags on the touch screen. When the organism is being interacted with is where the algorithm would be used, because there's no point in learning from just random numbers. So I guess the algorithm would take the x and y coordinates of the center piece into consideration, and each appendage would have its own version of the algorithm that learns independently from the others. For instance, if the user continually dragged the organism to the right side of the touch screen, it might be more attracted to that place when it isn't being interacted with. I hope that clarifies a little bit.

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you want?

Comment: Yeah, I have too many questions even to bother listing.  Add more detail.

Comment: Okay, I added some more detail, hope it helps.

Comment: so kind of glorified/enhanced Talking Tom Cat...http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/talking-tom-cat/id377194688?mt=8

Comment: Well it seems like Talking Tom Cat uses pre rendered animations whereas this would be rendering everything in real time, but I was thinking more along the lines of Electroplankton for the DS, at least as far as aesthetics go. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroplankton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that for your case, you should try to sit down and write down what are the variables that you can observe and what are the variables that you want to predict

- Observable variables: position of the appendage, how many times a specific one is interacted with, for how long, ...
- Variables you want to predict: which appendage will be interacted with next time, ...

Once you have the input variables and output variables, you can try to go through the list of standard machine learning algorithms. There are Weka(Java), Rapidminer, KNIME ... which are both libraries and standalone tools. Try to throw your problem at the available tools and see if you are doing better than chance.

If you are, tune its parameters. If you are not performing better than chance, you should ask your Data Mining/Machine Learning friends. They will know best what will work for your problem.

Other things that might affect your choice of algorithms:

- Are there hidden states?
- Are the variables independence?

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, all you'd need to do is have an array of, for example, the appendage coordinates, then just average them out and have it move towards that point on the screen